# Inserting a Question Within a Statement

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

Is it ok to insert a question within a statement?  Would this sentence be ok?

> "Sure the phone maybe obsolete years down the road because of the advances in the technology and the operating system, but can't we just enjoy it for now(.)?"

I put the period in closing parenthesis, because of it is ok to write a sentence like that, whether to use a period or a question mark.

Comment: It's your stylistic choice whether to use a full stop or a comma before ***but*** (or alternative orthography, such as a hyphen or ellipses), but this doesn't affect the basic principle - those final 7 words ***are*** a question (albeit probably rhetorical, not really expecting an answer), so they ***must*** be followed by a question mark.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "can't we just enjoy it for now" is a question, so it should end with a question mark. The first part of it is just leading up to the question.

Also note that you should use "may be" (two words) here instead of "maybe".

Comment: Yes. This isn't a "question within a statement". It's a question that is phrased as a complex sentence. While complex sentences may be difficult to understand at times, there's nothing inherent wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

A [rhetorical question](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/rhetorical-question-examples.html) (a question used to establish the topic, but which you yourself intend to answer) is nevertheless still a question.  For example:

> If the primary concern is safety, **would it not be better to ban young people from playing sports?**  I think not ...

You can include a question within a statement as a direct quote, in which case you include the question mark:

> If we were to ask, **"Is it better to ban all young people from playing sports?"** I think the answer would be a resounding "No!"

or an indirect quote, in which case you rephrase the question:

> If we were to ask **whether it is better to ban all young people from playing sports**, I think the answer would be a resounding "no".